# How do I display the value in the Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

How do I display Price value($) in `textbox` next to a `label` when user checks the `radio button`, select one of item from `listBox`, and then clicks the `button`?

Is there way to do it on the form1.cs[Design] using the properties? Or do I need to set them up in code level?

[listBox item example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nthf6.png)

EDIT: Solved this in Code-level.

Comment: get the selectedIndex in the *listbox* and see if the *radio button* is checked or not and pass these conditions in the *button_click* event after which the value will be displayed in the *textbox*

Comment: you cannot perform this alone with the help of the **forms** properties, you hardly need any code to circumvent this. A very naive question though.

Comment: Can you provide your design and explain a bit that how you want to execute your requirement, its not clear by the description here.

Comment: based on the image, 1. user checks radio button, 2. user select one of list item, 3. user clicked button1, 4. price value need to be shown in text field after user clicks button. Sorry if my questions are low-level. Pretty much still a starter level. (<6mth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without any code.
Also I'd recommend you to check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - just a few simple rules can make your chances to get a good answer on this site much better.

And there is not much of coding needed to solve your problem. Take a look on the Events tab in Property view in form designer. A few event handlers to process user input and some fields inside your class to store the data - I assume it is not some serious business app you're dealing with, so all the code you need for this to work would be like 20 lines tops -)